# Delete pandas cells values not included in list

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Given the following list:

```
a = ['1', '2', '12', '5']
```

I am trying to delete all values from the Dataframes cells which don't match the elements in the list. I know for sure that every value from the list appears only once in each row of the Dataframe.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'0' : ['1','4','5','5'],
           '1' : ['4','1','12','10'],
           '2' : ['10','12','4','2'],
           '3' : ['2','10','10','4'],
           '4' : ['5','2','2','1'],
           '5' : ['12','5','1','12']})


    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   4   10  2   5   12
1   4   1   12  10  2   5
2   5   12  4   10  2   1
3   5   10  2   4   1   12
```

The important aspect is to maintain the order of the matching numbers from the list in the Dataframe.

The result should look like this:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   1   2   5   12
1   1   12  2   5
2   5   12  2   1
3   5   2   1   12
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
#pandas 0.24+
df = test.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x.isin(a)].to_numpy()), axis=1)
#pandas below
df = test.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x.isin(a)].values), axis=1)
print (df)
   0   1  2   3
0  1   2  5  12
1  1  12  2   5
2  5  12  2   1
3  5   2  1  12
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([i for i in list(x) if i in ' '.join(a)]), axis=1)
```

**Output**

```
   0   1  2   3
0  1   2  5  12
1  1  12  2   5
2  5  12  2   1
3  5   2  1  12
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`numpy.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) in a python generator:

```
import numpy as np

# For latest version of pandas
pd.DataFrame(x[np.in1d(x, a)] for x in test.to_numpy())

# Otherwise use
pd.DataFrame(x[np.in1d(x, a)] for x in test.values)
```

[out]

```
   0   1  2   3
0  1   2  5  12
1  1  12  2   5
2  5  12  2   1
3  5   2  1  12
```

---

This method should also be faster than `DataFrame.apply`

#### Benchmarking

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(x[np.in1d(x, a)] for x in test.to_numpy())

712 µs ± 19.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)


%%timeit    
test.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x[x.isin(a)].to_numpy()), axis=1)

4.58 ms ± 185 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Did you mean `pd.DataFrame(x[np.in1d(x, a)] for x in test.values)`?

Comment: .`to_numpy` is the preferred method in the latest version of `pandas` - more info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html)